# How do I display a photo of an authorized user?

Tags: angular, angular-template

How do I display a photo of an authorized user? Tried to do so:

```
  <div *ngIf="authTokenService.currentUserData">
    <img class="img" src="assets/img/empty_photo.png" [(ngModel)]="authTokenService.currentUserData.user_photo" name="user_photo">
  </div>
```

but gives an error:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name:
>   'user_photo'

Comment: Is `authTokenService.currentUserData.user_photo` a url? or a image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use NgModels because their only used in forms or inputs; you can just simply change the source (attr src) to the users img url like this:

```
<div *ngIf="authTokenService.currentUserData">
    <img class="img" [src]="authTokenService.currentUserData ? authTokenService.currentUserData.user_photo : 'assets/img/empty_photo.png'" name="user_photo">
</div>
```

and btw this *ngIf for the container element is pretty useless in this case because it cannot even reach the empty image if there's no user

Comment: this means the `authTokenService.currentUserData.user_photo` is null